# How to pre-compile these files prior to startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How to pre-compile these files prior to application startup, since this is taking considerable amount of time in each page load.

```
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/alert.js  (0ms)  (pid 26396)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/tab.js  (0ms)  (pid 26396)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/collapse.js  (0ms)  (pid 26396)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/dropdown.js  (0ms)  (pid 26396)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/modal.js  (0ms)  (pid 26396)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/affix.js  (0ms)  (pid 26396)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark them "required" in `assets/javascripts/application.js"

Use `//=require_tree.` to include all JS files within `/javascript` files to be compiled. Or write the file names manually in order.

You can read the comments in application.js for instructions.

By the way, did you see the messages in development mode? If so, that's correct even you asked Asset Pipeline to compile them. Assets are only compiled at production mode, not development or test mode.

Comment: How do I compile assets in dev mode? rake precompile:assets

Comment: @Sam, how about you check the compile effect by starting server in proudction mode? That may be better. `RAILS_ENV="production" rails server`

Comment: @Sam, the command is `rake assets:precompile`, see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets. But I still prefer using production mode to check effect. By insist default method(no compile in development) you can force visitor to update cache if your JS file changed in production.